# AngularJS: include not working from a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive and I would like to use it to include an html content to the document after clicking on it.

Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/u2KUKU3WgVf637PGA9A1?p=preview

JS:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {

})
.directive('addFooter', ['$compile', '$rootScope', function($compile, $rootScope){
    return {

     restrict: 'E',
         template: '<button>add footer</button>',
         controller: 'MyController',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.bind( "click", function() {
                scope.footer = "'footer.html'";

       })}
    };
 }])
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="footer.html">
    FOOTER
  </script>

<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <add-footer></add-footer>

    <div ng-include="footer"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Not sure why it is not working, as it worked fine before it was moved into the directive. Outside the directive, I was also referencing to $scope.footer with some link. I tried using $rootScope, but also no effect. Any tips please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. Remove unnecessary quote symbols:

```
element.bind( "click", function() {
    scope.footer = "footer.html"; // not "'footer.html'"
});
```

Second. You should notify angularjs that you have asynchronously updated scope values:

```
element.bind("click", function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.footer = "footer.html";
    });
});
```

Or like that

```
element.bind("click", function() {
    scope.footer = "footer.html";
    scope.$apply();            
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, although I've just spotted another issue: when I put this directive into ng-repeat, it doesn't work. Any idea why is that? Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/u2KUKU3WgVf637PGA9A1?p=preview

Comment: This is because `ng-repeat` creates its own scope, use `.$parent` to access to controller's scope. `'scope.$parent.footer' = 'footer.html'`